# How do you run multiple automation studio jobs in parallel?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

I've built a welcome series in Automation Studio that sends an initial email, waits 3 days and fires off the 2nd email and finally waits another 7 days before firing off the final email.

If I put a csv file into my enhanced FTP location, the file gets picked up and Automation Studio starts running the automation.

When I add another file, the automation shows up in Automation Studio as queued while it is waiting on the original automation to run. Surely I'm doing something wrong as having to wait 10 days for an automation to complete before the next one starts seems somewhat flawed.

I looked at the API examples [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api/) however it appears that you can only trigger an automation, not pass information into Automation Studio.

Is anyone able to give me some insight into how to create a welcome series in Automation Studio where it can be triggered per customer without a 10 day queue time each?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing one of the primary use cases for Journey Builder.  Unfortunately, you don't have that in Automation Studio.

If you don't want to use JB, you should use the copy function within Automation Studio and make 7 copies.   You would probably want to make 7 copies of the Data Extensions and not mix the data, or make data compilation the last step on day10.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach 1 - 
Set the automation to load the data into a DE. You then set a seperate scheduled job to run the triggers you need on that data. (you can use recordadddate and default to current date if there is no time stamp.

Possible approach 2
Set the automation to load data into a DE that journey builder than use (best scenario)

Possible approach 3 - 
As Timothy mentioned.